# Display a yearly summary by month in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that has a `date/time` field and am trying to figure out how to run a report so that I can view the sum of the amount between each month separately in the 2012 year.

The table has 2 fields, `Amount` and `TimeStamp`, and I'm trying to return a report like this:

- January, 2012: $221.20
- February, 2012: $150.20

etc etc.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this easily in SQL Server?  I want to avoid writing a seperate query for each individual month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using the MONTH and YEAR Functions on SQL.

```
SELECT
    SUM(Amount) as [Amount]
    ,MONTH(TimeStamp) as [Month]
    ,YEAR(TimeStamp) as [Year]
FROM
    [MyTable]
GROUP BY
     MONTH(TimeStamp)
     ,YEAR(TimeStamp)
```